# How to specify Regexp for unicode cyrillic characters in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, encoding, character-properties

```
#coding: utf-8
str2 = "asdfМикимаус"
p str2.encoding #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
p str2.scan /\p{Cyrillic}/ #found all cyrillic characters
str2.gsub!(/\w/u,'') #removes only latin characters
puts str2
```

The question is why `\w` ignore cyrillic characters?

I have installed latest ruby package from http://rubyinstaller.org/. 
Here is my output of `ruby -v`

```
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]
```

As far as i know 1.9 oniguruma regular expression library has full support for unicode characters.

Comment: on Linux (ruby 1.9) gsub remove all characters -  irb(main):006:0> str2.gsub(/\w/u,'') => ""

Comment: @aaz: it shouldn't (see my answer); probably you have an old version?

Comment: I would rename this question as "How to specify Regexp for unicode characters in Ruby 1.9", since this is not related to win32 nor to (only) cyrillic.

Comment: you are right. its a bug in ruby 1.9.1p0, in ruby 1.9.1p376 all works well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is as specified in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html): `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and thus doesn't target any unicode character.

You probably want to use `[[:alnum:]]` instead, which includes all unicode alphabetic and numeric characters. Check also `[[:word:]]` and `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: BTW, we can thank Run Paint Run Run for writing this documentation.